# Not able to access shiny dashboard through company domain

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-server, shinydashboard

I built a shiny dashboard "shiny_testing" and it's working fine. I run the app through below command

```
runApp("shiny_testing", host = "0.0.0.0", port = 3333)
```

Now I am able to use it myself and share it with my colleagues through my local network ip http://11.11.11.111:3333/ BUT I want to share company's url http://shiny.mycompany.com so I forwarded the ip to company's url so that my colleagues use the dashboard through my company's url.
Problem is that after few inactive seconds the dashboard on company's url gets grey out (disconnected) whereas the dashboard on local system ip is working fine.
Dashboard on company's url starts working fine after the refresh but I don't users to keep refreshing it every minute.

Please suggest a way through which I can share the dashboard through company's URL. I just want to host on local network.

Let me know if you want any further info to better understand.

Comment: any solution for the same?